# I can't define DiscountedPrice

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a discount calculator. I can't define the variable DiscountedPrice in my program

Python 3.5 on a desktop

```
#programmed by 
#Discount Calculator
#Jan 29, 2018

#Explanation of program
print("This program will determine if a discount will be applied based 
off the quantity purchased. ")

#State Unit Price Variable
UnitPrice=int(99)

#State Unit Quantity Variable
UnitQuantity=int(input("Please input the number of units purchased. "))

#Calculate Initial Cost
InitialCost=UnitPrice*UnitQuantity
print("Your initial cost will be $",InitialCost)

#State the Total Cost Variable
TotalCost=InitialCost-DiscountedAmount


#Calculate equation to determine if discount will be applied
if UnitQuantity < 10:
DiscountedAmount = 0
print("There will be no discount applied to this purchase.")
elif UnitQuantity >= 10 and UnitQuantity <= 19:
DiscountedAmount = float(0.1) * UnitPrice
print("There will be a 10% discount applied to your purchase of 
$",InitialCost)
print ("Your total with discount come to $", TotalCost)
elif UnitQuantity >= 20 and UnitQuantity <= 49:
DiscountedAmount = float(0.2) * UnitPrice
print("There will be a 20% discount applied to your purchase of 
$",InitialCost)
print ("Your total with discount come to $", TotalCost)
elif UnitQuantity >= 49 and UnitQuantity <= 99:
DiscountedAmount = float(0.3) * UnitPrice
print("There will be a 30% discount applied to your purchase of 
$",InitialCost)
print ("Your total with discount come to $", TotalCost)
else: UnitQuantity >= 100
DiscountedAmount = float(0.4) * UnitPrice
print("There will be a 40% discount applied to your purchase of 
$",InitialCost)
print ("Your total with discount come to $", TotalCost)
```

Should be able to display after user input if they will receive a discount up to 40%

Comment: What is your error? What is preventing you from defining that variable? I don't see any `DiscountedPrice` in your program.

Comment: sorry it was DiscountedAmount*

Comment: I dont know python but looks like you are using DiscountedAmount before you declared it. Should be the same like for InitialCost or UnitQuantity.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are very new to programming. The variables defined in a Python code are not symbolic (unless you define them so), so you can't expect the value of `TotalCost` to be updated if and when `DiscountedAmount` changes. Also, you need to initialize a variable before using it.

I your code, you can't use `TotalCost=InitialCost-DiscountedAmount` without declaring the variable `DiscountedAmount` (Use `DiscountedAmount = 0`). Also, it will be a one time computation and value will be stored in `TotalCost`. You need to recompute `TotalCost=InitialCost-DiscountedAmount` this expression everytime the value of `DiscountedAmount` changes due based on the input, inside each `if` case.

Comment: Thank you, I made some changes everything is working except its printing out to outcomes instead of 1 and I am trying to figure out why it is doing that

Comment: This program will determine if a discount will be applied based off the quantity purchased. 
Please input the number of units purchased. 10
Your initial cost will be $ 990
There will be a 10% discount applied to your purchase of $ 990
Your total with discount come to $ 891.0
There will be a 40% discount applied to your purchase of $ 990
Your total with discount come to $ 594.0